# How to print every nth index of a python list on a new line?

Tags: python, list, printing, split

I'm trying to print out a list and for every 5 indexes, it prints a new line. So for example, if I have:

```
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

the output would be:

```
  1 2 3 4 5
  6 7 8 9 10
```

I tried this so far:

```
   lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

   for i in lst:
       if len(lst) > 5:
          print(lst,'\n')
```

but all I get is:

```
   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 

   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 

   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 

   .......
```

How could I do this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's your output if `len(list)` isn't divisible by your index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i in [a[c:c+5] for c in range(0,len(a),5) if c%5 == 0]:
    print(*i)
```

the output will be:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

also you can replace `5` with any other number or variables.

Comment: Hi, do you mind if I use the `*i` argument unpacking for the formatting in my answer? It's a lot better than the current `" ".join()` i've got going on

Comment: @Primusa Sure it is ok, I will also vote-up your answer.

Comment: No problem @Primusa, I think that is good if you look at `sep=` in `print` function too. it is good. something like this `print(*i, sep='-')` it will print: `1-2-3-4-5`

Answer (score 3):

Used a for loop with a step:

```
n_indices = 5
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for i in range(0, len(lst), n_indices):
    print(lst[i:i+n_indices])

>>>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

If you want to be fancier with the formatting you can use argument unpacking like so: `print(*list[i:i+n_indices])` and get outputs in this format:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: I guess he wants a formatted output only .join: print(' '.join(lst[i:i+indices]) ... will be good for him :)

Answer (score 0):

A bit more idiomatic than the other answers:

```
n = 5
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for group in zip(*[iter(lst)] * n):
    print(*group)
```

---

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

For larger lists, it's also much faster:

```
In [1]: lst = range(1, 10001)

In [2]: n = 5

In [3]: %%timeit
    ...: for group in zip(*[iter(lst)] * n):
    ...:     group
    ...:
236 µs ± 49.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [4]: %%timeit
    ...: for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
    ...:     lst[i:i+n]
    ...:
1.32 ms ± 184 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for i in range(0, len(a), 5):
    print(" ".join(map(str, a[i:i+5])))
```

It will give you desired output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```