# Count to 10 and Next line

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with my code, and I can't figure it out. My code is supposed to print 0 to input number subtracted by 1. Here's my code:

```
num = int(input(''))

if num > 50:
    print('Number must be below 50')
else:
    for num in range(0, num):
        if num >= 0:
            print(num, end=" ")
```

The output must next line every 10 numbers, but my output only displays one line.

```
Input:
15
Output:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

Output must be

```
Input:
15
Output:
0•1•2•3•4•5•6•7•8•9
10•11•12•13•14
```

Comment: You want to learn about "modulo"

Comment: `if num >= 0:` is always true here, since you start the range at zero. So you can (and should) remove the if statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print every nth index of a python list on a new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54301753/6045800)

Answer (score 3):

```
num = int(input(''))

if num > 50:
    print('Number must be below 50')
else:
    for i in range(0, num):
        print(i, end=" ")
        if i % 10 == 9:
            print()
```

For clarity, don't reuse the variable name `num` inside and outside the loop. You can easily introduce bugs that way.

Answer (score 0):

You are not printing a new line after printing every 10 numbers. As you are starting from 0, you have to print a new line whenever you get a multiple of 9. The code should look like this:

```
num = int(input(''))

if num > 50:
    print('Number must be below 50')
else:
    for i in range(0, num):
        if i >= 0:
            print(i, end=" ")
        if i % 9 == 0:
            print("")
```

Comment: ```if i >= 0:``` is not necessary here, you can remove it as the loop starts from 0.